# Bug in raw reputation report?

Tags: bug, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-badges, reputation-page

On October 31st, I earned the Epic badge on SO (woohoo!).

This badge is awarded for getting >=200 daily points score 50 times.

However, if I go to the raw reputation report page<sup>†</sup> the summary at the bottom tells me that I've only earned >=200 points 49 times.

```
days represented 1088
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 22 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 49 days
earned 6 reputation from suggested edits
```

I understand that these things aren't always in sync or up-to-date, but I thought this raw rep page should be correct. It does show my latest points, so it's clearly got all the data; it just seems to be the summary figures that are off.

I've exceeded 200 points a further 4 times since getting the badge as well, so I don't think it's just an off-by-one counting error either.

Is this a bug, or is it counting different to what the Epic badge counts? Or maybe I really have only done it 49 times, and the badge was awarded prematurely?

I've tried doing a recalc, but that didn't change the stats.

<sup>† link is https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, although don't bother clicking as you'll see your rep report not mine.</sup>